# Nlog timestamp while using tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, nlog

I have something like this call structure:

Program -calls-> Service1.Function1 -calls-> Service2.Function2 -calls-> HTTP Call

At the end there is a HTTP call, so all my calls are made via async/await.

Here's a example:

```
        async function1()
        {
            logger.Info("START Function1 with parameters xy");

            logger.Info("CALL Function2 with parameters xy");
            await Service2.Function2();
            logger.Info("RET Function2 with parameters xy");

            logger.Info("END Function1 with parameters xy");
        }

        async function2()
        {
            logger.Info("START Function1 with parameters xy");

            await HTTPClient.Call();

            logger.Info("END Function1 with parameters xy");
        }
```

Using NLog I get this log

```
2021-11-04 14:44:12.6996|INFO |Service1.Function1 : START  Function1 with Parameters: xy
2021-11-04 14:44:12.6996|INFO |Service1.Function1 : CALL   Function2 with Parameters: xy
2021-11-04 14:44:12.6996|INFO |Service2.Function2 : START  Function2 with Parameters: xy
2021-11-04 14:44:17.7004|ERROR|Service2.Function2 : A task was canceled.
```

If you look at the timestamp, it shows always the exact same timestamp till the awaited HTTP Call is made. I think this has to do with the asynchronous (async/await) structure. How can i enable the "real" timestamps?

Comment: What is the expected/desirable output?

Comment: Can you please add some minimal code to be able to reproduce this? We can't see where the START, CALL, START etc. are being logged

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I added example code above. The expected behaviour would be, that the timestamps should differ, or am i wrong? I think the logmessages cannot all be written in the exakt same time. As you see in the last line, the call is cancelled because, it took longer than 5sec. I want to investigate where in my functions i loose so much time.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite clear without code (how do you log in between async/await).

But you probably want

```
<time type="AccurateUTC" />
```

in nlog.config.

See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Time-Source